# Can I use an HTTP POST in a preStop lifecycle hook in a Kubernetes job?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

I currently have the following lifecycle hook in my kubernetes config:

```
lifecycle:
      preStop:
        httpGet:
          path: /path
          port: 8080
```

I would like to call the shutdown endpoint of spring boot actuator in this hook, but this endpoint requires a post request instead of a get. Is this in any way possible or should I define my own endpoint that shuts down my app gracefully?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

You can add an `exec` lifecycle hook since `httpPost` is not a valid one, and assuming you have `curl` in your containers:

```
lifecycle:
  preStop:
    exec:
      command: ["curl", "-XPOST", "http://URL"]
```

Comment: Thanks! After doing some more reading, it was one of the solutions I was considering. I'll add curl to the container and will try it.

Comment: Is there any other alternative to this ? I am looking forward to use distroless images in the container which don't have `curl`